# Pythonic way to traverse etc shadows

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a logic using python :

```
 cat /etc/shadow | awk -F: '($2 == "" ) { print $1 " does not have a password "}'
```

If the above returns the output for the user i will do

```
passwd -l <username>
```

I am trying to implement the above logic using python , but i am not really sure if it is working out in that way; here is my python code:

`/etc/shadow` looks like

```
root:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
daemon:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
bin:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
sys:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
sync:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
games:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
man:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
lp:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
mail:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
news:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
uucp:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
proxy:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
www-data:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
backup:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
```

**CODE**

```
with open("/etc/shadow") as file:
   for line in file:
       line = line.rstrip()
       if line[line.find(":")+1:line.find(":")]=="":
          print "This is a problem"
       elif line[line.find(":")+1:line.find(":")]=="*":
          print line[line.find(":")+1:line.find(":")]
       else:
          print "All Good"
```

The above code returns "This is a problem" , which isn't right

Comment: `line.find(":")` will always give first occurence of ":". Problem here is that second `line.find(":")` will again return the index of first ":".

Comment: Note that `line.find(":")` always starts searching at the beginning of the string. "This is a problem" because `line[x+1:x]` will always result in an empty string.

Comment: Consider using a dictionary here if it makes sense for your data. The user could be the key, and then a list of each user’s properties in `/etc/shadow`. It also makes importing the data much easier in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split your lines on the ":" separator and check the value at the second position (which is at index 1 of course):

```
data = """
root:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
daemon:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
bin:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
sys:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
sync:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
games:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
man:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
lp:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
mail:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
news:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
uucp:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
proxy:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
www-data:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
backup:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
"""

for line in data.strip().splitlines():
    row = [part.strip() for part in line.split(":")]
    if row[1] == "":
        print("this is a problem")
    elif row[1] == "*":
        print row[1] 
    else: 
        print "all good"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re` to extract desired column:

```
import re

data = """root:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
daemon:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
bin:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
sys:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
sync:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
games:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
man:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
lp:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
mail:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
news:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
uucp:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
proxy:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
www-data:*:17709:0:99999:7:::
backup:*:17709:0:99999:7:::"""

groups = re.findall('(.*?):(.*?):(.*?):(.*?):(.*?):(.*?):(.*?):(.*?):', data)

if all(g[1].strip() for g in groups):
    print('All good')
else:
    print('This is a problem')
```

This prints:

```
All good
```

Explanation of this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/esJBgh/1). In the second group (`g[1]`), you have the shadowed password (`*`), or empty string.

Comment: re is overkill here. You can just split the line on ":"

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Second group should be g[2] ? no ?

Comment: @DeathADDER Indexing is starting from `0` - so `g[0]` is first group, `g[1]` is second group.

Comment: ah okay, but we aren't comparing g[1]=="" ?

Comment: @DeathADDER `g[1].strip()` returns empty string `""`, if there isn't any asteriks. The `all()` built-in function will evaluate the empty string as False and returns False - which prints "This is a problem". Documentation to `all()` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
with open("/etc/shadow/") as ff:
   for line in ff:   
        login_name,pwd,remainder=line.split(":",maxsplit=2)
        print(login_name,pwd) # change it as you like
```